# Regarding improper functionality of emulator in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

i am new here, but i checked the site, it does not contain my question, hence not duplicate. Actually, in my android studio v 1.1.0, emulator does not launch default activity automatically when started in android studio. What i mean is that when i click the green (play) button to run my project, my emulator is launched. When it loads and is ready to be unlocked, after unlocking my default activity should run automatically but it does not. Just The Home screen is shown no matter how much i keep waiting. No error reported in LogCat, neither any exception or anything wrong with code. So to run, I have to right click on my activity and click run MainActivity from the available options. So, how do i make the emulator automatically launch my default activity?

Comment: in a real device the default activity is started?

Comment: Have you edited your "run configuration" to say "launch default activity"?  https://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html#RunConfig

Comment: yes i have set it to launch default activity